# jQuery binds fail after the load function

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

I'm doing the AJAX requests with the library intercooler.js, but I tried with native AJAX and I got the same result.

**I submit the login form (which it is in a modal):**

```
<form id="loginForm" role="form" class="login-form" ic-post-to="{% url 'login' %}" ic-on-error="handleFormError(xhr,'loginForm');" ic-on-success="deleteAllErrors('loginForm');$('#loginModal').modal('hide');update('navbar');" data-toggle="validator">{% csrf_token %}...</form>
```

**When "ic-on-success" (success request) I refresh the div with id="navbar" (the header links). This function causes jQuery stop working:**

```
update('navbar');

function update(idDom){
   $('#update-' + idDom).load(' #' + idDom);
}
```

**Okey, now the div with id="navbar" (the header links) got refresh and the logout link appear, but this does not work anymore:**

```
<div id="update-navbar">    
   <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">   
      <a class="pointer" ic-get-from="{% url 'logout' %}" ic-on-success="update('navbar');"><i class="lnr lnr-exit"></i> Cerrar sesi&oacute;n</a>
   </div>
</div>
```

It's like jQuery stop working. I repeat, I tried with native AJAX and `$("#target").click(function() {...` too but the bind does not work.

I have to refresh the whole page pressing F5 so that the logout link works again.

Answer (score 0):

[Bind events on dynamic created elements inserted by AJAX (check box)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17122485/bind-events-on-dynamic-created-elements-inserted-by-ajax-check-box)

try

`$(document).on('click',"#target", function() {...`

Comment: It's works but would I have to do that with all the components? Over 50 AJAX definitions in all the buttons and a tags..... :S that's so primitive. If my component it's a link have I to manually reinstantiate it? some of my a tags are like this: `<a class="pointer" ic-get-from="{% url 'logout' %}" ic-on-success="update('navbar');"><i class="lnr lnr-exit"></i> Cerrar sesi&oacute;n</a>`